# Multiprocessing task in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, resources, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out how to perfom a multiprocessing task with an unusual formulation.

Basically, given two lists containing 10 matrices for each list, I have to check if applying an operation (that I'll call fn) gives the same results if the input is (A, B) or vice versa (B, A).

With a sequential approach, the solution is streightforward:

```
#Given
A = [matrix_a1, ... , matrix_a10]
B =  [matrix_b1, ... , matrix_b10]

AB_BA= [fn(A[i], B[i])==fn(B[i], A[i]) for i in range(0, len(A)) ]
```

The next task is a bit strange because it requires setting strictly more than ten threads and applying multiprocessing. The restriction is that you can not assign all the single comparisons to ten different processes because the remaining processes will be unused. I do not know why the request seems to be using "process" and "thread" interchangeably.

This task seems a bit confusing because in multiprocessing, generally, you set the maximum number of workers, not the minimum.

I tried to use a solution that uses a ProcessPoolExecutor, as follows:

```
def equality(A, B,i):
    res= fn(A[i], B[i]) == fn(B[i],A[i] )
    return(res)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    idx=range(0, len(A))
    results= executor.map(equality, A, B, idx)

    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to check resource usage. I have naively tried to monitor the CPU usage using the ubuntu system monitor as well as "top" from the command line.

In addition, this solution is the most efficient among those I tried, but there is not a direct specification to use at least 11 workers, so this solution seems not to stick with what was requested.

I also tried other solutions, such as using pool directly. This causes to evoke 10 python instances using top, but again, not more than 10. Here's what I tried:

```
def equality(A, B):
    res=fn(A, B) == fn(B,A )
    return(res)

with mp.Pool(20) as p:
    print(p.starmap(equality, ((A[i], B[i]) for i in range(0, len(A)))))
```

Do you have any suggestions to address this request as well as monitor the resource usage to be sure it is working as expected?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Your statement of the problem is very difficult to understand.  What about this interpretation: compute ten values of fn(A, B) in parallel using ten processes.  At the same time, compute ten values of fn(B, A) in parallel using ten more processes.  All 20 processes should be started as simultaneously as possible.  Finally compare each pair of results for equality.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, I agree that this is very likely to be the correct way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you had published the actual problem word for word, since your description is a bit unclear. But this is what I know (or think I know):

Unless the amount of CPU processing done by your worker function `equality` is great enough so that what is gained by running the function in parallel more than offsets the additional multiprocessing overhead you would not otherwise have if not using multiprocessing (i.e. starting processes, moving data from one address space to another, etc.), your multiprocessing code will run more slowly. Therefore, you should design your worker function to do the most work possible and to pass as little data as possible.

When you specify ...

```py
results = executor.map(equality, A, B, idx)
```

... your `equality` function will be invoked once for each element of `A`, `B` and `idx`. So what is being passed is not the entire lists `A` and `B` but rather individual elements (e.g. `matrix_a1` and `matrix_b1`). Therefore, there is no point in even passing an `idx` argument:

```py
def equality(matrix_a, matrix_b):
    """
    matrix_a and matrix_a are each single elements of
    lists A and B respecticely.
    """
    return fn(matrix_a) == fn(matrix_b)


def main():
    from os import cpu_count
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

    A = [matrix_a1, ... , matrix_a10]
    B =  [matrix_b1, ... , matrix_b10]

    # Do not create more processes then we have either
    # CPU cores or the number of tasks that need to submit:
    pool_size = min(cpu_count(), len(A))
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size) as executor:
        AB_BA = list(executor.map(equality, A, B))
        # This will be a list of 10 elements, each either `True` or `False`:
        print(AB_BA)

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So we will be submitting 10 tasks to a pool size of 10. Internally there is a "task queue" on which all the arguments being passed to `equality` exist:

```
matrix_a1, matrix_b1 # task 1
matrix_a2, matrix_b2 # task 2
...
matrix_a10, matrix_b10 # task 10
```

Any process in the pool that is idle will grap the next task in the queue to work on and the results will be returned in task submission order. But since `equality` is such a short-running function *unless function `fn` is sufficiently complicated*, there is the possibility that the pool process that grabs the first task can complete it and then grab the second task before some other pool process is dispatched by the operating system and can grab it. So there is no guarantee that all 10 tasks will be worked on in parallel by 10 pool processes even if function `fn` is sufficiently CPU-intensive. If you were to insert a call to `time.sleep(.1)` at the beginning of `equality`, that would give the other pool processes a chance to "wake up" and grab its own task from the task queue. But that would slow your program down even more since sleeping for this purposes is totally non-productive. But the point I am trying to make is that you cannot ensure that all pool processes will always be active concurrently.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I see your point, and I guess the solution to this request is just how I decompose the problem, as Paul Cornelius suggested. Do you have any suggestions for what concerns the "resource monitoring" problem?

Comment: Please publish the problem description as given to you so I know exactly what is trying to be accomplished as far as process/thread utilization. I cannot determine this from your description. Let me know when you have done this by creating a comment with @Booboo in it.